# Frontend Post Excerpt field mapping

Tags: posts, front-end, excerpt

I'm trying to create a form with gravity forms.
I need to merge two fields to one Excerpt. 
I can't give the Excerpt field a merge tag. So I'm trying to use an custom field.

My question is now: what is the WP Parameter to map the Excerpt to the post.

I've tried: the_ excerpt, _excerpt, post_excerpt, etc.

But it never appears in the Excerptfield...

Comment: `$post->post_excerpt = 'This is the Excerpt` doesn't work? I imagine you would first need to get the post object, then set the field manually.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the Gravity Forms plugin but if you are using the `wp_insert_post` function to insert the new post, you just use 'post_excerpt'.

**example:**

```
$new_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Post Title',
  'post_content'  => 'Post Content',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_excerpt'  => $custom_excerpt_field
);

wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Not sure if I completely understand your question, so I've misunderstood something please let me know..